# Is it possible to force a teamcity vcs root to always use the same commit?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

My build configuration pulls code from multiple vcs roots. As part of my build process I build an open source project from github, which unfortunately has just introduced a dependency that breaks the build on my server.

Is there any way I can change the specification of the VCS root to limit it to the commit before the dependency was introduced? I don't want to manually run a specific commit as this would force the other repository in the build back to the same point in time, which would mean I'm never building my latest code. For reasons outside of the scope of this question, I need to build all projects from source, so can't take a pre-compiled version.

Is it possible to force teamciy to always check out the same commit of a VCS root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of projects are using tags to identify versions so probably you can use it.
Or if you always need only one version you can fork repo and add branch/tack on your copy
Unfortunately git refspec does not provide possibility to specify commit by hash.